# Виртуальная звуковая карта на Visual Studio C++

Tags: windows, c++

Подскажите, в каком направлении искать информацию о том, как сделать программу - виртуальная звуковая карта. Которая будет перехватывать звук с микрофона, изменять его и выводить через вируальное устройство.

Answer (score 1):

Прямой перехват звука с микрофона потребует написания своего звукового драйвера, что является достаточно трудоемкой задачей.

Посмотрите на [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/), возможно, это то, что вам нужно:

> JACK - аудио сервер с низкими задержками, написанный для любы операционной системы, достаточно совместимой с POSIX. В настоящее время существует для Linux, OS X, Solaris, FreeBSD и Windows. Он может подключат несколько клиентских приложений для аудио устройств, и позволяет им обмениваться аудио друг с другом. Клиенты могут работать как отдельные процессы, как обычные приложения, или как "модули" в сервере JACK.